# Can't ping Amazon EC2 second private IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that has 2 private IP addresses:

In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have:

```
auto lo
 iface lo int loopback

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 172.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.240.0
```

After the network restart, all IPs works fine! The problem is that the internal DNS uses only the first IP. If I try to ping from another instance using the host name, I only obtain the first IP. How can I use both? Something like a round robin?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with built-in DNS since the hostname of the instance has the IP address built right into the name, e.g. `ip-172-16-20-10.us-west-2.compute.internal`. This is just a simple/naïve mapping (every RFC-1918 private address name will give you back the corresponding IP -- even for instances that don't exist).  It sounds like you are doing something unusual here with the multiple addresses... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Solved with internal DNS and route53

Comment: Yes, that would do it. :)